Why is this called the “Global Opening”?
I’m looking through the Wikipedia page of all chess openings. Many funny names can be found, but one of these, which is
1.h3 e5 2.a3
Is called “The Global Opening”.

It doesn’t seem to be very global. So why is it called so? Is there any history or some event that gave it its name?

just speculation, but "global" could refer to the context of the board, e.g. the pawns are on opposite sites of the board (or "world"), the "ends of the Earth" as it were.

Chess.com calls 1. h3 e5 a3 the "Anderssen Opening" which seems to be a transposition from the 1. a3 line (see here).  Chess.com calls the 1. h3 by itself the Clemenz Openeing (see here).
